# How to authenticate Bitstamp HTTP API v2 request?

Tags: c#, api, authentication, httprequest

I'm trying to issue an order: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/sell/btceur/?key=xxxxxxxx&signature=BA3CBF267C54965441207FAD25AD7C1C4B9110CE49BA7F2752F7DA79828BF5A1&nonce=1509725707&amount=0.002&price=6267.0

I'm getting the 403 Forbidden code and this JSON message:

```
{
    "status": "error", 
    "reason": "Missing key, signature and nonce parameters.", 
    "code"  : "API0000"
}
```

I'm developing in C# but also tried manually with Postman and got the same results.

For the signature calculation, I used the code found in posts similar to this one:

```
#region Methods

private string GetSignature(string customerId, string publicApiKey, string privateApiKey, Int32 nonce)
{
    string msg = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", nonce,
        customerId,
        publicApiKey);

    return ByteArrayToString(SignHMACSHA256(privateApiKey, StringToByteArray(msg))).ToUpper();
}

private static byte[] SignHMACSHA256(String key, byte[] data)
{
    HMACSHA256 hashMaker = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
    return hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
}

private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
}

private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] hash)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}

#endregion
```

How can I authenticate the request successfully?

UPDATE:
I crosschecked the signature generation against the python code and it is ok. What else can it be?

Comment: did you insert a real key?  The key in the URL is : xxxxxxxx

Comment: Yes sure, I did insert a real one, I just masked it here

Comment: Websites often give false error messages to prevent hackers from learning from the error messages.  403 is usually a general error message that just means something is wrong.  You may not be using V2.  See intro : https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on the same issue, trying to implement a Bitstamp Client in Qt5.
As of now, I was unable to get a different JSON-Response than the 403-Error you wrote about, but I assume trying to put the parameters in a JSON-Body like

```
{
  "key":"<your-key>,
  "signature: "<the-hmac>",
  "nonce": "<your-nonce>"
}
```

would be worth a shot.

If you figured out, what caused the response and how to solve the problem - or at least ideas how to investigate this further, I would be glad to be informed.

[EDIT:]
I figured out, you need to send the parameters in the POST-Body as URL-Encoded String, so works by inserting

```
nonce=nonce&signature=signature&keyapi_key
```

in the Body. You also need to make sure you provide the right `Content-Type`-Header, which in this case is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In QT5 I've managed to do it with:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/"));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Kassiopeia 0.0.0");
request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

uint nonce = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
QByteArray signature = this->hmacSha256(m_customer_id, m_api_key, m_api_secret, nonce);
QByteArray body = "nonce="+QString::number(nonce).toUtf8()+"&signature="+signature+"&key="+m_api_key.toUtf8();

qDebug() << "Request Nonce: " << nonce;
qDebug() << "Request Body:  " << body;

reply = manager->post(request, body);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        this, SLOT(onReadReady()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(onSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
```

And if someone needs them, these are the slots:

```
void Exchange::onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError error)
{
    qDebug() << "Network Error: " << error;
}

void Exchange::onSslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{
    QString errorString;
    foreach (const QSslError &error, errors) {
        if (!errorString.isEmpty())
            errorString += '\n';
        errorString += error.errorString();
    }

    qDebug() << "SSL Error: " << errorString;
}

void Exchange::onFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << "Finished Request.";
}

void Exchange::onReadReady()
{
    QString strReply = (QString) reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument jsonReply = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
    qDebug() << "Read: " << jsonReply.object();
}
```